# Tier Interaction Profiling pane missing in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012, profiling

I've used the tier interaction profiler to great effect a lot in the past, but now I'm in visual studio 2012 and not seeing it? Has it been moved to only live in ultimate edition or some such? I can profile, I just don't have the tier interaction profiler which is of course the best feature of visual studio profiling!

Am I just doing something wrong? Tried instrumentation and sampling, attaching, launching, selecting the project from the solution, can't seem to find the TIP anywhere..

Has the TIP been removed or some other such?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the "Ultimate" edition?

The [2012](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd557764%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [2013](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd557764%28v=vs.120%29.aspx) versions of the MSDN doc for "Tier Interactions View" says:

> Requirements

```
Visual Studio Ultimate
```

The [2010](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd557764%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) version does not.

Also, there's a [thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/6b923a5d-f5f7-4cf0-8f32-38784962496a/vs11-beta-tier-interaction-does-not-show?forum=vstsprofiler) that suggests at there might be a 32-bit-only restriction on TIP.